# Beginner full body routine without squats

Tags: strength, bodybuilding, beginners

My gym does not have a squat rack, and I can't seem to find any beginner strength routines without squats. Any suggestions? Is it possible to do something like strong lifts with split squats instead? Thanks

Comment: Answers to [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7676/1771) might help you think around this problem. Dumbbell lunges, while not a substitute for squats, fit well as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do bodyweight squats. If it seems too easy, try one-leg squats or you can hold free weights while squatting.
Split squats are also a good alternative.
Always add more weight to your squats when you can do 10-15 reps because if you do higher reps, your squats will just increase endurance without gaining muscle.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how strong you are you can also clean and press a bar and lower it on your back..  Be careful though and start with low weight until you get the hang of it..

Comment: This is a good solution for ~3-4 weeks, as your squat weight will increase much faster than your clean weight. Also consider that you'd have to do a behind-the-neck press after each squat set. From personal experience I can say I really hated that once I reached 30kg.

Comment: A clean and front squat allows greater loads than trying to clean-and-press the bar to a back squat position. It's still not a maximal front squat and definitely not a max back squat, but it's pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to find a new gym. Failing that, cleaning the weight and front squatting it will most likely result in larger quads anyway. Will just have to find other exercises to help hit the glutes and hamstrings

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to change your gym,I would suggest you to go for lite exercise.Don't go for strong lifts if you are new to gym.